# NSMutableDictionary with weak-references: warning when using CFRetain as a callback

Tags: cocoa, callback, default, nsmutabledictionary, weak-references

I'm trying to create a mutable dictionary that has weak-references for the value objects (the keys behave normally).
This is how i'm trying to do it:

```
+ (id)mutableDictionaryUsingWeakReferencesWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)capacity
{
    CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks keyCallbacks = {0, CFRetain, CFRelease, CFCopyDescription, CFEqual, CFHash};
    CFDictionaryValueCallBacks valueCallbacks = {0, NULL, NULL, CFCopyDescription, CFEqual};    
    id<NSObject> obj = (id)(CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, capacity, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks));
    return [obj autorelease];
}
```

Unfortunately I get a warning (*Initialization from incompatible pointer type*)in when declaring the keyCallbacks, and i've tracked it down to using CFRetain and CFRelease. For some reason these callbacks do not match the required prototypes (CFDictionaryRetainCallback and CFDictionaryReleaseCallback)

In the documentation it says that an example CFDictionaryRetainCallback should look something like this:

```
const void *MyCallBack (
   CFAllocatorRef allocator,
   const void *value
);
```

But the existing CFRetain is declared as

```
CFTypeRef CFRetain(CFTypeRef cf);
```

It's missing the allocator parameter and that's why I think the compiler gives a warning: it's not a perfect match in the signature of the function.

Has anybody tried to do something like this?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm working on iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the default `CFRetain`/`CFRelease` behaviour, this should work:

```
void MONDictionaryReleaseCallback(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void* value) {
#pragma unused(allocator)
    assert(value);
    if (0 != value) {
        CFRelease(value);
    }
}
```

the retain callback should be easy to implement from there.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
This is one valid solution. You can also check out the other one i proposed in a topic below (uses kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks constant).

Answer (score 5):

Don’t Do That. Use `NSMapTable`.

Comment: Nice :). Didn't know about NSMapTable. It seems to do the trick with weak-references.

Comment: Damn it! ... I forgot to mention i'm working on iphone and NSMapTable isn't available on it. Sorry. My original question is still standing.

Comment: Good news! NSMapTable has since been added to iOS 6 :)

Comment: [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nshashtable-and-nsmaptable/) recently posted a good article about `NSMapTable` with examples.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using the kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks constant instead of manually declaring the key callbacks. 
The code now looks like this:

```
id<NSObject> obj = (id)(CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, capacity, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &valueCallbacks));
```

However, i'm still curious why isn't my initial code working

Comment: Go take a look at the callbacks struct definition, and then at the definitions of each of the functions. They take more arguments than `CFRetain`/`CFRelease` do. The default CFType callbacks are likely just thin wrappers around those functions.

Comment: @Kevin: as i said in my original post, I did notice that the callback and function signatures are different. I was just wondering why this is because the documentation for the constant kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks states the following: 
_The retain callback is CFRetain, the release callback is CFRelease, the copy callback is CFCopyDescription, the equal callback is CFEqual._

Comment: Poorly worded documentation. It's describing what the callbacks perform rather than what the literal function pointer is.

Comment: It probably is. The funny thing is that the included CFCopyDescription and CFEqual can be used. Only CFRetain and CFRelease have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind playing with the runtime a bit, [this](https://gist.github.com/firelizzard18/6326536) is something I'm working on for a project of mine (it works ATM but it's a bit sloppy). It dynamically creates a new subclass of any object you add and set that object's class to the subclass. The subclass keeps an array of objects that should be notified whenever the object is deallocated. The dictionary adds itself to this array so that it can remove the object if it's ever deallocated.